# Why run() and sleep() cannot guarantee us running and sleeping states in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I read somewhere that using the methods run() and sleep() cannot guarantee us the running and sleeping states for a thread in Java.Is there some way I can explicitly demonstrate it?

Comment: Recently you read where?

Comment: @EJP : http://java9s.com/tutorial/core-java/threads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Recently I read somewhere that using the methods run() and sleep() cannot guarantee us the running and sleeping states for a thread in Java.

If the `run()` method of the thread has been called and the thread is spinning (i.e. not writing log files or reading from a socket) but completely doing CPU tasks then it will be in the `RUNNABLE` state.  However, the OS/CPUs may be busy doing other things so there is no guarantee that the thread is actually working at any one point in time.  Of course, just because you've written the `run()` method doesn't mean that the thread has actually started or anything.

If you call `Thread.sleep(...)` then the thread will be in a `TIMED_WAITING` state.  However, the thread could be interrupted by another thread and awoken or the sleep time could have expired of course.

The [thread states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) are:

- NEW - A thread that has not yet started is in this state.
- RUNNABLE - A thread executing in the Java virtual machine is in this state.
- BLOCKED - A thread that is blocked waiting for a monitor lock is in this state.  Waiting to enter a `synchronized` block for example.
- WAITING - A thread that is waiting indefinitely for another thread to perform a particular action is in this state.  `Object.wait();` for example.
- TIMED_WAITING - A thread that is waiting for another thread to perform an action for up to a specified waiting time is in this state.  `Object.wait(timeoutMillis)`
- TERMINATED - A thread that has exited is in this state.

> Is there some way I can explicitly demonstrate it?

You can certainly do something like the following:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long x = 0;
        for (long y = 0; y < Long.MAX_VALUE; y++) {
            x += y;
        }
        System.out.println("it will never get here of course: " + x);
    }
}, "Running-Thread").start();
```

Once the thread starts, it will spin and will be in the `RUNNABLE` state.  You can use jconsole to see all of the thread states.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // always a good pattern
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}, "Sleeping-Thread").start();
```

Once the thread starts, it will sleep and show to be in the `TIMED_WAITING` state.